# how to merge selectedOptions in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I use react-select and I'm new.I have a component called Example

```
const colourOptions = [
  { value: '1', label: '1', color: '#00B8D9' },
  { value: '2', label: '2', color: '#0052CC' },
  { value: '3', label: '3', color: '#5243AA' },
];

class Example extends React.Component {
      state = {
        selectedOption: null,
      }

      render() {
        const { selectedOption, onHandleChange } = this.props;
        return (

          <Select
            onChange={onHandleChange}
            options={colourOptions}
          />

        );
      }
    }

    export default Example;
```

In another file we have a functional Component

```
export default function UserProfile() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    setSelectedOption(selectedOption)
    console.log(selectedOption)
  };

  return (
    <div>

      <Example onHandleChange={handleChange} selectedOption={selectedOption}/>
      <Example onHandleChange={handleChange} selectedOption={selectedOption}/>
      <Example onHandleChange={handleChange} selectedOption={selectedOption}/>

    </div>
  );
}
```

By changing every Example, the value of the previous selectedOption is removed.
how to put (merge) all selectedOptions inside one object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect all the selected options into one Array. Please find the link to working solution
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-xk3bw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";
import Example1 from "./Example";
import Example2 from "./Example";
import Example3 from "./Example";

export function UserProfile() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({});
  const [allselectedOption, setAllSelectedOption] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(allselectedOption);
 },[allselectedOption]);

  const handleChange = selectedOption => {
    setSelectedOption(selectedOption);
    let newSelectedOptions = [...allselectedOption,selectedOption]
    setAllSelectedOption(newSelectedOptions)
    console.log(newSelectedOptions);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Example1 onHandleChange={handleChange} selectedOption={selectedOption} />
      <Example2 onHandleChange={handleChange} selectedOption={selectedOption} />
      <Example3 onHandleChange={handleChange} selectedOption={selectedOption} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: tanx @Amila This is great.The only problem is that it doesn't show the last choice. Can you help please?

Comment: @yaser.barati I updated the answer, please check. There are two options and you can select either one of them. You can use `useEffect` or else you can handle the logic inside the `handleChange` function.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to maintain a separate option values for all `Example` instances.

**Like this:**

```js
export default function UserProfile() {
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({ example1: '', example2: '', example3: '' });

    const handleChange = (key, selectedOption) => {
        setSelectedOption(prev => ({...prev, [key]: selectedOption}));
        console.log(selectedOption)
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Example1 onHandleChange={(value) => handleChange('example1', value)} selectedOption={selectedOption.example1}/>
            <Example2 onHandleChange={(value) => handleChange('example3', value)} selectedOption={selectedOption.example2}/>
            <Example3 onHandleChange={(value) => handleChange('example3', value)} selectedOption={selectedOption.example3}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**EDIT**
Working code is here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-mclaren-8s2z2?file=/src/UserProfile.js

Also quick note - the state updates are asynchronous so when you do console.log right after setting state, you may see the log printing old state.

Read [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) if you like